# How can you view the full error in visual studio 2017 community for MAC

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I am trying to edit some storyboards I created in visual studio community 2017 for Mac.

The problem is that I keep getting an error.

I'm sure I have some declarations wrong, the problem is that I can't see the full error

When I press open with-> Xcode Interface Builder, I get an error on the top of the screen and can't see the rest of it.

This is what I see:

[image: Error Shown]
Is there anyway to see the full error or something more specific than an one line message?

Comment: After installing VS for Mac, have you ever launched Xcode? At least once is required, because certain prerequisites must be installed that way.

Comment: I would see if there is any more information in the IDE log (Help - Open Log Directory). The single line error in the status bar is not that helpful in order to diagnose the problem.